# Simulations by row in R

Tags: r, simulation

I'm trying to obtain a 90% interval using quantiles over a simulation. I have a data set where each row contains a mean, sd, and number of simulations to run.

When I attempt to run the code it, for some reason, only creates the quantiles for the entire dataset, rather than using the information contained in each row as the simulation parameters. Is there any way to get this to work for each row?

Here is an example of what I'm working with:

```
avg <- c(24, 20, 29, 17, 22, 21)
sd <- c(5, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3.6)
sims <- 1000
df <- data.frame(avg, sd, sims)

df$Low90 <- round(quantile(rnorm(n = sims, mean = df$avg, sd = df$sd), prob = 0.05), 2)
df$High90 <- round(quantile(rnorm(n = sims, mean = df$avg, sd = df$sd), prob = 0.95), 2)

df
  avg  sd sims Low90 High90
1  24 5.0 1000 14.13  32.32
2  20 4.0 1000 14.13  32.32
3  29 5.0 1000 14.13  32.32
4  17 3.0 1000 14.13  32.32
5  22 3.0 1000 14.13  32.32
6  21 3.6 1000 14.13  32.32
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `tidyverse` method that uses `pmap` so you only need to iterate through the rows once for an arbitrary number of quantiles. The problem in your original approach is that `rnorm` is not vectorised over its `n` argument; try just running `rnorm(n = sims, mean = df$avg, sd = df$sd)` and note you get only one set of 1000 values.

Here, we'll use `pmap` to iterate through the rows, applying a custom function that takes as many quantiles as you have in a `probs` argument. We need to use `enframe` and `spread` to make these quantiles tibbles instead of a numeric vector, so that `unnest` keeps everything on the same row. The advantage is that now if you want, say, every percentile, you can just change the `probs` vector and get 100 new columns.

```r
avg <- c(24, 20, 29, 17, 22, 21)
sd <- c(5, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3.6)
sims <- 1000
df <- data.frame(avg, sd, sims)

library(tidyverse)
probs <- c(0.05, 0.5, 0.95)
quantile_tbl <- function(sims, avg, sd, probs) {
  rnorm(sims, avg, sd) %>%
    quantile(probs) %>%
    round(2) %>%
    enframe() %>%
    spread(name, value)
}
df %>%
  mutate(quantiles = pmap(select(., sims, avg, sd), ~quantile_tbl(..1, ..2, ..3, probs))) %>%
  unnest()
#>   avg  sd sims    5%   50%   95%
#> 1  24 5.0 1000 15.96 24.04 32.42
#> 2  20 4.0 1000 13.53 20.17 26.72
#> 3  29 5.0 1000 20.59 29.13 37.27
#> 4  17 3.0 1000 11.83 17.08 21.76
#> 5  22 3.0 1000 16.75 22.05 27.17
#> 6  21 3.6 1000 14.87 20.79 26.94
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Could you explain the advantages to this method? My benchmarking may be wrong but seems v slow?

Comment: Haven't benchmarked, there is more overhead here with `enframe` and `spread` but there is only one iteration no matter the number of columns. For any in-memory dataset it should be pretty fast regardless. The main advantage is that if you want to make more than two quantile columns, you do not need a new line per column which makes it much more readable. If you need 100 quantiles you just change to `probs <- seq(0.01, 0.99, 0.01)`.

Comment: I see, seems 5 times as slow when only using 2 percentiles, but I imagine if you want 10,20,etc... this method is much more efficient. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `apply`,

```
df$Low90 <- apply(df, 1, function(x) round(quantile(rnorm(n = x[3], mean = x[1], sd = x[2]), prob = 0.05), 2))
df$High90 <- apply(df, 1, function(x) round(quantile(rnorm(n = x[3], mean = x[1], sd = x[2]), prob = 0.95), 2))
df

 avg  sd sims Low90  High90
1  24 5.0 1000 16.08 32.08
2  20 4.0 1000 13.65 26.78
3  29 5.0 1000 20.55 36.96
4  17 3.0 1000 11.94 22.26
5  22 3.0 1000 17.13 26.95
6  21 3.6 1000 14.79 26.84
```

What we are doing is using the `apply` function, with margin 1, which means go row wise. Then within each row, we get the `means`, `sd` and `simulation` number, and run it through your simulation function.

A `dplyr` solution would be using the `rowwise` function,

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% rowwise %>% 
  mutate(Low90 = round(quantile(rnorm(n = sims, mean = avg, sd = sd), prob = 0.05), 2))
```